# C++ passing pointer address in function

Tags: c++, pointers

The code below uses an octahedron as a starting 3D shape, ( I found it on the web) and after some tweaking I can't still make it work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h> /* must include for the offsetof macro */
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

struct XYZ {
    GLdouble x;
    GLdouble y;
    GLdouble z;
};

struct FACET3 {
    XYZ p1;
    XYZ p2;
    XYZ p3;
};


void Normalise(XYZ *p_input)
{
    double magnitude = 0;
    magnitude = sqrt((p_input.x * p_input.x )+ (p_input.y * p_input.y) + (p_input.z * p_input.z));
    p_input.x = p_input.x / magnitude;
    p_input.y = p_input.y / magnitude;
    p_input.z = p_input.z / magnitude;

}

int CreateNSphere(FACET3 *f,int iterations)
{

   int i,it;
   double a;
   XYZ p[6] = {0,0,1,  0,0,-1,  -1,-1,0,  1,-1,0,  1,1,0, -1,1,0};
   XYZ pa,pb,pc;
   int nt = 0,ntold;

   /* Create the level 0 object */
   a = 1 / sqrt(2.0);
   for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
      p[i].x *= a;
      p[i].y *= a;
   }
   f[0].p1 = p[0]; f[0].p2 = p[3]; f[0].p3 = p[4];
   f[1].p1 = p[0]; f[1].p2 = p[4]; f[1].p3 = p[5];
   f[2].p1 = p[0]; f[2].p2 = p[5]; f[2].p3 = p[2];
   f[3].p1 = p[0]; f[3].p2 = p[2]; f[3].p3 = p[3];
   f[4].p1 = p[1]; f[4].p2 = p[4]; f[4].p3 = p[3];
   f[5].p1 = p[1]; f[5].p2 = p[5]; f[5].p3 = p[4];
   f[6].p1 = p[1]; f[6].p2 = p[2]; f[6].p3 = p[5];
   f[7].p1 = p[1]; f[7].p2 = p[3]; f[7].p3 = p[2];
   nt = 8;

   if (iterations < 1)
      return(nt);

   /* Bisect each edge and move to the surface of a unit sphere */
   for (it=0;it<iterations;it++) {
      ntold = nt;
      for (i=0;i<ntold;i++) {
         pa.x = (f[i].p1.x + f[i].p2.x) / 2;
         pa.y = (f[i].p1.y + f[i].p2.y) / 2;
         pa.z = (f[i].p1.z + f[i].p2.z) / 2;
         pb.x = (f[i].p2.x + f[i].p3.x) / 2;
         pb.y = (f[i].p2.y + f[i].p3.y) / 2;
         pb.z = (f[i].p2.z + f[i].p3.z) / 2;
         pc.x = (f[i].p3.x + f[i].p1.x) / 2;
         pc.y = (f[i].p3.y + f[i].p1.y) / 2;
         pc.z = (f[i].p3.z + f[i].p1.z) / 2;
         Normalise(&pa);
         Normalise(&pb);
         Normalise(&pc);
         f[nt].p1 = f[i].p1; f[nt].p2 = pa; f[nt].p3 = pc; nt++;
         f[nt].p1 = pa; f[nt].p2 = f[i].p2; f[nt].p3 = pb; nt++;
         f[nt].p1 = pb; f[nt].p2 = f[i].p3; f[nt].p3 = pc; nt++;
         f[i].p1 = pa;
         f[i].p2 = pb;
         f[i].p3 = pc;
      }
   }

   return(nt);
}


int main()
{
    FACET3 *facet;
    int facets = CreateNSphere(facet, 2);
    printf(" Result: %d", facets);
}
```

I am trying to make this code run. I am basically trying to generate coordinates for a sphere from a octahedron.but when I use g++ to compile it I get this:

```
sphere_model.cpp:32:28: error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:32:40: error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:32:54: error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:32:66: error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:32:80: error: request for member ‘z’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:32:92: error: request for member ‘z’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:33:10: error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:33:22: error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:34:10: error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:34:22: error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:35:10: error: request for member ‘z’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
sphere_model.cpp:35:22: error: request for member ‘z’ in ‘p_input’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ*’
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p_input` is a pointer, you should use the `->` operator instead of the `.`

Comment: @Trt Trt: That's completely unrelated.  You have another question, make another post.

Comment: gdb says "0x00000000004011df in CreateNSphere(FACET3*, int) ()"

Comment: The segmentation fault is because you call your "CreateNSphere" function with a non-initialized "f" parameter. In your "main", you have to initialize the "facet" variable with something correct. As the "CreateNSphere" code uses "f" as an array of 8 elements, you can change your declaration of "facet" from "FACET3* facet;" to "FACET3 facet[8];".

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to your second question, which you've posted as a comment.

The function `CreateNSphere` assumes that it's passed an array containing 8 FACET3 objects. In main(), you need to either initialize `facet`, or create it as an array instance rather than as a pointer. Either of these would work:

```
FACET3 facet[8];
int facets = CreateNSphere(facet, 2);
```

or

```
FACET3 *facet = new FACET3[8];
int facets = CreateNSphere(facet, 2);
```